# how to connect bootstrap template to sql table?

Tags: css, asp.net, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a asp.net website. I use a bootstrap template. I put the link of that here. https://shapebootstrap.net/demo/html/evento/index.html#event-carousel . I want to connect Event section to sqlserver and the pictures load from the database table. i test that with repeater and datalist control in asp.net but it does not work correctly and the style of template destroy.For example when I used the repeater the pictures load from database but all of them are in one column.
How can I do that? I create a new section like event section. but I want to connect it to sql server. I searched for it and understand that I should use 2 repeater like 2 for loop and use group by. For example the datatable that load from database has 12 rows. I should devide it for example into 4*3 and connect datatable to repeaters. I do not know how can I do it?

```
        <section id="Prefer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
                <div id="Prefer-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">

                    <h2 class="heading" style="text-align:right;">Prefer</h2>
                    <a class="even-control-left" href="#Prefer-carousel" data-slide="prev" ><i class="fa fa-angle-left" ></i></a>
                    <a class="even-control-right" href="#Prefer-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="single-event">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/event/event1.jpg" alt="event-image">
                                        <h4>Chester Bennington</h4>
                                        <h5>Vocal</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="single-event">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/event/event2.jpg" alt="event-image">
                                        <h4>Mike Shinoda</h4>
                                        <h5>vocals, rhythm guitar</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="single-event">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/event/event3.jpg" alt="event-image">
                                        <h4>Rob Bourdon</h4>
                                        <h5>drums</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="single-event">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/event/event1.jpg" alt="event-image">
                                        <h4>Chester Bennington</h4>
                                        <h5>Vocal</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="single-event">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/event/event2.jpg" alt="event-image">
                                        <h4>Mike Shinoda</h4>
                                        <h5>vocals, rhythm guitar</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="single-event">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/event/event3.jpg" alt="event-image">
                                        <h4>Rob Bourdon</h4>
                                        <h5>drums</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="guitar">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/guitar.png" alt="guitar" />
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>
</section><!--/#Prefer-->
```

Comment: A good start is to show us some code of how you perform this

Comment: I edit my question.